# Two variants of the Littlewood-Offord theorem

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, discrete-geometry, additive-combinatorics, tropical-geometry

I found two different looking things being called the Littlewood-Offord theorem,

1. If $\vec{a} \in \mathbb{R}^k \setminus 0$ and $t \in \mathbb{R}$ then there are $O(\frac{2^k}{\sqrt{k}})$ points $x \in \{1,-1\}^k$ such that $\vec{a}.\vec{x}=t$
2. If $\vec{a} \in \mathbb{R}^k$ is such that at least $n$ of the $a_i$ have $\vert a_i \vert \geq 1$ then for $x \sim \{1,-1\}^k$ uniformly at random and $I$ an interval of length $2$ we have $Pr_x[ \vec{a}.\vec{x} \in I] \leq O(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})$

   - Can someone kindly explain if these two are related to each other or not? Is one derivable from the other?
   - Can someone give an expository (lecture notes) reference of the proof of the later version?

Comment: Do you mean to divide by the square root of the number of nonzero entries of $a$ in 1? Else I can take $a = (1,0,0,...)$ and $t = 1$ and then the $2^{k-1}$ solutions $x = (1,\star,\star,...)$ to $a\cdot x = t$ would contradict the claim for $k$ large.

Comment: (Or did you mean $(\mathbb{R} - \{0\})^k$?)

Comment: Anywho I think this works. Wlog since all the $a_i$ are nonzero they're all positive (absorb the sign into the $x_i$). Let $T:=\{S_x : a\cdot x = t\}$, where I've written S_x for the subset of $\{1,...,n\}$ where $x_i=1$. Claim: for every pair of distinct $S, S'\in T$ we do *not* have that $S\subseteq S'$. Proof: otherwise the respective $x,x'$ would have $a\cdot x' > a\cdot x$. OK, so we've found an antichain in the power set of $\{1,...,n\}$ (ordered with respect to inclusion) of the same size as the set of $x$'s we wanted to estimate.

Comment: Sperner's theorem says that therefore $|T|\leq {n\choose \lfloor n/2\rfloor)}$. By Stirling this gives what you wanted. To prove Sperner, consider the set of permutations that send some prefix $\{1,...,k\}$ to a set inside our $T$. Claim: given such a permutation, you can recover the corresponding subset of $T$. (Note that I only said *some* prefix.) Proof: otherwise $\{1,...,k\}\subseteq \{1,...,k'\}$ would both be sent to subsets of $T$, with $k<k'$, contradiction. Thus the count of this subset of $S_n$ is $\sum_{S\in T} |S|! (n - |S|)!$, which is $\leq n!$ since it's in $S_n$.

Comment: Each term in the sum is at least $\lfloor n/2\rfloor! \lceil n/2\rceil!$ since the middle binomial coefficient is maximal. Hence we find that $|T| \lfloor n/2\rfloor! \lceil n/2\rceil!\leq n!$, QED.

Comment: Sorry I switched $n$ and $k$! I got the proof of Sperner off of Wikipedia, which says that Erdos was the first to prove your claim 1 using Sperner.

Comment: For the second claim you asked about, just fix the values of the $x_i$ outside the set where $a_i\geq 1$ (again you can assume all of the $a_i$ are positive) and run the above argument except now you've reduced to the case where all $a_i\geq 1$. Then instead of the $a\cdot x' > a\cdot x$ you get $a\cdot x' > a\cdot x + 2$, so both of them can't be in the same interval of length $2$. Otherwise the argument is the same.

Comment: @alpoge Thanks for your efforts! I am a bit unclear about the last part of your argument. If you are fixing the $x_i$ for those $i$ where $a_i \geq 1$, then you are taking a probability over the free $x_i$ coordinates and there are at most $k-n$ of them. ($k$ and $n$ as I have defined in my second point). Then probability over the Sperner upper-bound would give  the upperbound on the probability as $\frac{1}{2^{k-n}} \frac{k!}{(k-n)!n!}$. This doesn't look like $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$.

Comment: Hey! In the argument you fix the $x_i$ for $i$ such that $|a_i| < 1$ --- hopefully that clears things up! Lemme know if it works ok now. [For some reason the app won't let me tag you in my comment, so hopefully you see this.]

Comment: That was actually my typo! I wanted to say $a_i  < 1$. The final expression I wrote down uses $a_i < 1$ and it doesn't seem like the needed $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$.

Comment: Wait I'm still confused --- fixing the $x_i$ such that $|a_i| < 1$ reduces to the case where all $a_i > 1$, and then you're working in an $m$-dimensional space (with $m\geq n$), so by the previous argument you get a savings of $O(1/\sqrt{m})\leq O(1/\sqrt{n})$, no? [The number of $i$ such that $|a_i| < 1$ is at most $k-n$, but those are fixed.]